# How to directly scan a SQL indexed table

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq, ado.net

I have a SQL table with indexes containing leads to call. About 30 users will be calling these leads. To be sure that there is no two users calling the same lead, the system has to be instant.

So I would like to go this way:

- Set the table to the right index
- Scan the table for a lead I can call (there are conditions), following the index
- When I have a call, indicate that the record is "in use"

Here are my issues:
- I can't find any way to set a table to an index by c# code
- Linq requires dataContext (not instant) and ADO requires DataSet

I have not found any resource to help me on that. If you have any, they are more than welcome.

Sorry if I may sound ignorant, I'm new to SQL databases.

Thank you very much in advance!
Mathieu

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "set the table to the right index".  Since you're new to SQL, I suspect you may not know that you probably do not need to do that step (indeed, I don't even know what that step would BE!).

Comment: So if I want my record in order of a DateTime column because I want to manage them from the older to the more recent, how do I do? I create the index on SQL server and I put the same condition in my "SELECT ... ORDER BY samecondition" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked on similar systems before.  The tact we took was to have a distribution routine that handled passing out the leads to the call center people.  Typically we had a time limit on how long the lead was allowed to be in any one users queue before it was yanked away and given to someone else.

This allowed us to do some pretty complicated things like giving preference based on details about the lead as well as productivity of the individual call center person.

We had a very high volume of leads that came in and had our distribution routine set to run once a minute.  The SLA was set so that a lead was contacted within 2 minutes of us knowing about them.

To support this, your leads table should have a AssignedUserId and probably a date/time stamp of when it was assigned.  Write a proc or some c# code which grabs all the records from that table which aren't assigned.  Do the assignment routine, saving the changes back to the table.  This routine should probably take into account how many leads they are currently working and the acceptable number of open leads per person in order to give preference in a round robin distribution.

When the user refreshes they will have their leads.  You can control the refresh rate in the UI.

Comment: This is very clever actually. This is not the system we used to use, but this could raise the performance a lot. This is definitly something good! Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how your requirement of being "instant" relates to the use of an index. Accessing a table by index is not instantaneous either.

To solve your problem, I would suggest to lock the whole table while a lead is being called. This will limit performance, but it will also ensure that the same lead is never called by two users.

Example code:

```
Begin Transaction
Lock Table
Search for Lead
Update Lead to indicate that it is in use
Commit Transaction (removes the lock)
```

Locking a table in SQL Server until the end of the transaction can be done by using `SELECT * FROM table WITH (HOLDLOCK, TABLOCKX) WHERE 1=0`.

*Disclaimer:* Yes, I'm aware that cleaner solutions with less locking are possible. The advantage of the above solution is that it is simple (no worrying about the correct transaction isolation level etc.) and it is usally performant enough (if you remember to keep the "locked part" short and there is not too much concurrent access).